# Last input from the array list fails

Tags: java

I'm doing this problem for hobby Javascript course. The idea is when you input an "empty" the code prints out the last input from the list. It works okay when I test it in Netbeans but when I try to submit to the server so I can return it and get a point I get a error:

> ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

What is the problem?

```
ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList<>();
while (true) {
    String luettu = lukija.nextLine();
    if (luettu.equals("")) {
        break;
    }

    lista.add(luettu);
}

System.out.println(lista.get(lista.size() - 1));
```

Comment: *java* is not *javascript*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, if the list is empty you still try and get an element first check this using:

```
if(!lista.isEmpty()){
    System.out.println(lista.get(lista.size() - 1));
}
```

Comment: Now I don't get the build error if I run " " while my list is empty but my problem still stays.

Comment: @Fchicken it means that your scanner is still empty, either your scanner can't access the file or the file is empty I would need some more information to help you out

Comment: I found the problem. There was a spelling error in preloaded layout that course was using so the public class "name" didn't mach with the netBeans project. Because original assigment was "fill this code so x thing happens". But thanks I learned what to do to prevent building error while list is empty.

Answer (score 0):

In your case 
lista.size() = 0

and thus 
lista.size() - 1 = -1

and this cause you to ask 
lista.get(-1)

which is out of bounds

make sure lista.size() > 0 before you get lista.size() - 1

Answer (score 0):

What if the first input is an empty line?
In that case, lista.size() will return 0, and subtracting 1 from it will attempt to reach the -1 element in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code snippet:

```
ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList<>();
while (true) {
    String luettu = lukija.nextLine();
    if (luettu.equals("")) {
        break;
    }

    lista.add(luettu);
}

System.out.println(lista.get(lista.size()>0?lista.size() - 1:lista.size()));
```

The line basically checks and adjusts itself to act as per the size of the list. A list with  one element should never have -1 while accessing the only element